# Как правильно перевести на русский "Atmospheric penetration" и "Atmospheric removal"?

Tags: перевод

Данные термины - Atmospheric penetration и Atmospheric removal - встречаются в англоязычной технической литературе, посвященной геоинформационным системам. Первый термин употребляется в следующем контексте:

> Coast lines and shores are well defined. It may be used to find textural and moisture characteristics of soils. Vegetation appears blue.

А второй в таком:

> This combination provides a "natural-like" rendition, while also penetrating atmospheric particles and smoke. Healthy vegetation will be a bright green and can saturate in seasons of heavy growth, grasslands will appear green, pink areas represent barren soil, oranges and browns represent sparsely vegetated areas....

Не могу сообразить, каким должен быть их правильный перевод на русский язык. Буду признателен за советы!

Пример где используются эти термины (the link which shows the usage of these two terms) - https://lv.eosda.com/?lat=38.71123&lng=-101.96411&z=8&day=true&s=Landsat8&id=LC80320332017097LGN00&cb=false&b=SWIR2,SWIR1,NIR . Если нажать на восклицательный знак рядом с "Atmospheric penetration" или "Atmospheric removal", то можно получить описания (if you press on exclamation mark near these two terms - Atmospheric penetration and Atmospheric removal - you will see their description).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Please note that questions asking for translations should indicate prior research effort: something you have already come up with and the reasons you didn't like the result. Thanks!

Comment: To me, they both can be translated like "Устранение атмосферных эффектов", but I'm not quite sure how to differentiate them to get two different and valid translations.

Comment: could you please add that to your post and elaborate on these terms a little bit? The excerpts you provide don't even use these terms, it would help a great deal to see the terms actually used. Thanks!

Comment: @Quassnoi. I made an update and provided a link to a real world application where these two terms are used and if you click on exclamation mark near the terms, you will see their descriptions. Though, unfortunatelly the terms themselves are not mentioned there.Please, have a look. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, I am more confused with the first term and do not quite get the idea, why it is "penetration"

Comment: I'm afraid this way it would be an offtopic for this site. Try to clarify the meaning here first: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi! But it will be the third SE to ask this question :) I guess, I will just have to make my own awkward translations.